# Missing table error while accessing a legacy PostgreSQL table with Grails

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, grails-orm

I have been trying to connect to a legacy table of a *PostgreSQL* database from my *Grails* App for a few days now without success.

**What I want**

All I want is to query this table (which has the users stored) from my grails app in order to check the login credentials. A user logs in the grails app and I have to check that the provided password matches the one stored in this table.

Since the table I am trying to access is called "*user*" (which is a keyword), I have created an alias view "*users*" which is the one I'm using from grails, just to avoid possible problems.

Below I'm providing additional information about my problem, hoping that someone could help me.

**Manual query result**

When doing `select * from public.users` directly from postgres in a console I'm getting the following result:

```
                id                    |   name    |           apikey          |          created           | about | openid |            password           | fullname |            email             | reset_key 
--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------------------+----------------------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------+----------+------------------------------+-----------
 ef8661be-6627-40e3-8b58-e78f3363680f | logged_in | this-is-an-api-key-sample | 2012-12-11 14:17:28.949515 |       |        |                               |          |                              | 
 0c49f23a-350c-43d9-a1ec-34057125acd7 | visitor   | this-is-an-api-key-sample | 2012-12-11 14:17:28.953194 |       |        |                               |          |                              | 
 591798d4-f85e-4bc2-a352-a41635c83653 | admin     | this-is-an-api-key-sample | 2013-04-10 15:08:47.104103 |       |        | thisisanencodedpasswordsample | admin    | username@email.com           | 
 25c8b15f-ec67-472b-b551-3c7112d4a2db | grails    | this-is-an-api-key-sample | 2013-04-10 15:12:44.257821 |       |        | thisisanencodedpasswordsample | grails   | username@email.com           |
```

---

From my grails app I have are the following files:

**Users Domain Class**

```
class User {
    String user_id
    String name
    String apikey
    String created
    String about
    String openid
    String password
    String fullname
    String email
    String resetKey

    static mapping = {
        version false
        autoTimestamp false
        table "public.users"
        resetKey column: "reset_key"
        created column: "created", sqlType: "timestamp without time zone"
        user_id column: "id", sqlType: "text"
        id name:  'user_id'
    }
}
```

**DataSource**

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    dbCreate = "validate"
    logSql = true
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.100:5432/ecodata"
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    dialect = net.sf.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    username = "ecodata"
    password = "******"
}
```

**POM dependencies**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**The error** I'm having when starting my grails app is:

> [...]  Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: **Missing table:
>   users**  [...]

I hope someone could help with this.
Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Why don't you call your table "users"?

Comment: Because the table is used by other applications... I'm spected to simply check the user credentials from it without changing anything.

Comment: You have `created` as a String when it is a date. You can generate the schema from Grails and see how it compares to the actual schema. You do this with http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Command%20Line/schema-export.html

Comment: Ok, can you show more stacktrace?

Comment: Maybe you should add the constraints?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I have posted below the solution I finally achieved to solve the problem since I think it could be useful somebody with a similar problem in the future.

Comment: James, about the date as a string, you are right, however in my case I'm not using that particular field, so it's not important for me to have it as a string instead of a date. Grails appears to be casting it automatically to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Follow up:

I have finally **solved the problem**! And actually it was my fault, although it was a tricky typo that was difficult to see...

In my dataSource you can see the following line:

```
url: "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.100:5432/ecodata"
```

But it actually should be:

```
url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.100:5432/ecodata"
```

I realized about the typo while I was debuging the depths of the grails connection to the database. I saw that everything but the url of the datasource had the proper configuration. The url filed had a default in-memory database value. That was strange... Then, checking carefully the dataSource again, I saw the colon instead of the equals. Damn! I like dynamic languages, but these kind of typos can be very frustrating...

First problem solved.

Another problem: **hibernate_sequence error** (also solved)

Once I solved the former problem, another error appeared:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing sequence or table: hibernate_sequence
```

After reading a bit, I found that this error was happening due to the validations that were being performed against the legacy database. I solved it removing the validations. This was done commenting the following line (also in the dataSource)

```
//    dbCreate = "validate"
```

*I hope this post could help someone in the future*. That's why I'm posting the solution to both, the problem I had initially and also to the `hibernate_sequence` issue.